# Free Tensorflow GPU 2.x memory python between executions n windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow

How can I close/free/kill TensorFlow GPU 2.1 memory usage on windows 10 using python code?

My code executes the following predictions

```
model.predict(video_1)

model.predict(video_2)

...

model.predict(video_155)
```

I would like to kill/free the GPU between each `model.predict` without having to physically close the python interpreter to free memory. How can one do that?

I want to free the memory that causes the following

```
2020-08-13 17:11:34.563606: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:243] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.30GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
```

Comment: Which variable do you want to free? video_x input file or output of model.predict ?

Comment: @AlperenKantarcı I want to free the tensorflow-gpu that is occupying the memory which I believe is the `CUDNN`

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to free all GPU memory because your model is also in the GPU. You should free input or output file from GPU There are two options here. Either you should free the input data or output data which is the result of model.predict(input).

You can try to use Python del function with either

```
del video_1
```

or

```
del output_1
```

then you should execute the following

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

Comment: it is okay to reload the GPU and model again, It is fine with me with the overhead.

Comment: then you can also del model and then use gc collect